# This is the code of lexical analyzer can anyone explain this code in detail?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

this is lexical analyzer code in c++ can any one explain me that code and also tell me how to read string from a file

```
using namespace std;
```

> function

```
int isKeyword(char buffer[]){
char keywords[32][10] = {"auto","break","case","char","const","continue","default",
                        "do","double","else","enum","extern","float","for","goto",
                        "if","int","long","register","return","short","signed",
                        "sizeof","static","struct","switch","typedef","union",
                        "unsigned","void","volatile","while"};
int i, flag = 0;
```

what is happening here? why we use strcmp and what its used for

```
for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
if(strcmp(keywords[i], buffer) == 0){
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}
 return flag;
}
```

> main

```
int main()
{
char ch, buffer[15];
ifstream fin("program.txt");
int j=0;

if(!fin.is_open()){
    cout<<"error while opening the file\n";
    exit(0);
}
    while(!fin.eof()){
    ch = fin.get();
```

what is happening here?

```
    if(isalnum(ch))
    {
      buffer[j++] = ch;
    }

    else if((ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') && (j != 0)){
            buffer[j] = '\0';
            j = 0;                  
            if(isKeyword(buffer) == 1)
                cout<<buffer<<" is keyword\n";
            else
                cout<<buffer<<" is identifier\n";
    }       
}   
fin.close();    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What about your research?

Answer (score 1):

overall idea is to have a data structure `keywords[n][m]` hold all the keywords and then read a file word by word and check whether the word is in the `keywords[n][m]` array or not i.e. whether it is a keyword OR not.
In the main function, a file is opened and is read word by word till end and the word is passed to  function `iskeyword()` to decide whether the word is keyword or not. Inside the `iskeyword()` function, we iterate through the 2-d array `keywords[n][m]` in a for loop and use the strcmp function to check whether the word string passed as input argument is same as an element of the 2-d array or not. If the word is in 2-d array then its a keyword and the function returns 1 and `is keyword` is printed on screen. Otherwise '0' is returned and 'is identifier' is output to screen.
[more about strcmp here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)
hope this helps!